# How to reference a DropDownList inside a DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DetailsView which contains several text boxes and also a DropDownList.

Now, what I want to do is to write an SelectedIndexChanged event for that DropDownList, but my problem is that I cannot reach it anymore/reference it.

If I just put a DropDownList right on the form it´s no problem but now winds it is inside the DetailsView it seems impossible to reach it.

Any suggestions?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Protected Sub DetailsViewAvtaleInfo_PageIndexChanging1(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewPageEventArgs) Handles DetailsViewAvtaleInfo.PageIndexChanging

    Dim DropDownListContractType As DropDownList = DirectCast(Me.DetailsViewAvtaleInfo.FindControl("DropDownListContractType"), DropDownList)
    Dim TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.DetailsViewAvtaleInfo.FindControl("TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth"), TextBox)

    If DropDownListContractType.Text = "Kjøp" Then
        TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

I know this is not right, but its as far as I get. I would want to just Write the code within the following sub but it just will not work:

```
    Protected Sub DropDownListContractType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)      Handles DropDownListContractType.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.DetailsViewAvtaleInfo.FindControl("TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth"), TextBox)

    If DropDownListContractType.Text = "Leasing" Then
        TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "...but it just will not work" - be more specific. Does it see your Dropdown in the first piece of code or just the second? Why not use FindControl() to get the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the markup for the dropdownlist, it should be like below **(Attached the method to the event)**:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListContractType" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListContractType_SelectedIndexChanged">                        
    <asp:ListItem Text="Kjøp" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Leasing" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Your code also have some issues:

1. Should be `DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text` instead of
   `DropDownList.Text`.
2. You have to cast the `sender` to `DropDownList` in `DropDownListContractType_SelectedIndexChanged` method.
3. You have to find the `NamingContainer` of `DropDownList` in `DropDownListContractType_SelectedIndexChanged` method

If you have the following code, it should work:

```
Protected Sub DropDownListContractType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim DropDownListContractType As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth As TextBox = DirectCast(DropDownListContractType.NamingContainer.FindControl("TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth"), TextBox)

    If DropDownListContractType.SelectedItem.Text = "Leasing" Then
        TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub DetailsViewAvtaleInfo_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewPageEventArgs) Handles DetailsViewAvtaleInfo.PageIndexChanging
    Dim DropDownListContractType As DropDownList = DirectCast(Me.DetailsViewAvtaleInfo.FindControl("DropDownListContractType"), DropDownList)
    Dim TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.DetailsViewAvtaleInfo.FindControl("TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth"), TextBox)

    If DropDownListContractType.SelectedItem.Text = "Kjøp" Then
        TextBoxLeasingPriceMonth.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tested the code above. If you have any issue, try to copy/paste the markup and code.

You can download my test project to compare with yours [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0OGxReFFWTFhVVlE/edit?usp=sharing).